# Extract CSS into HTML tags

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea

I have a simple HTML page with CSS code which I would like to use for web mail template. But in order to use it for e-mail I need to embed the CSS code int both HTML code. Is there some tool that can extract there CSS files code and embed it into the HTML code?

Is this possible with InteliJ?

Comment: im not quire sure what you are asking, but do you have a site example or code example?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure of what you're asking, but if what you mean is if you can have HTML and CSS in different files then the answer is yes.

You can do it by copying the CSS and pasting it into a new file and saving it as **style.css**. Then go to the  of your HTML file and add a .

Here's an example:

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p> This is an example :D </p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE

```
p{
  color: black;
}
```

Hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking to embed CSS styles for use in a HTML email template.

As far as I am aware,there isn't a tool that will do this for you, so you will have to do this manually.

You can drop the CSS into the `<head>` section using the `<style>` tag.

But in order to ensure support for Outlook, you will need to embed the styles inline.

https://litmus.com/blog/ is a good source of reading material for HTML email development.